# Create pdf having each page background in different color using DOMPDF

Tags: codeigniter, dompdf

I am generating reports using **DOMPDF** in **codeigniter**. This pdf have 10 pages in which 3 pages have yellow background (Page #2, #5 and #8 and entire page bgcolor needs to be yellow without margin or spacing) rest pages background color is white.

Also, i am using DOMPDF's **html5 parser** by setting "**DOMPDF_ENABLE_HTML5PARSER**" config as true. This is because my report html's contains html5 tags like footer.

> I googled this and found one solution as to put each page in separate "**body**" tag but generated output have all pages in yellow background.

Below is my html template:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Report</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reports/styles.css" />
</head>

<!-- Page #1 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Heading</h1>
      <ul class="index">
        <li>2. report 1</li>
        <li>5. report 2</li>
        <li>8. report 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #2 -->

<body style="background-color: #f2ab02">
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Report 1: Analysis &amp; Results</h1>
      <img src="/img/reports/human-face.png" class="imglogo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #3 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 1: (1/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">3</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #4 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 1: (2/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">4</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #5 -->

<body style="background-color: #f2ab02">
  <div>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <h1>Report 2: Analysis &amp; Results</h1>
      <img src="/img/reports/human-face.png" class="imglogo" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #6 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 2: (1/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">6</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #7 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 2: (2/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">7</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #8 -->

<body style="background-color: #f2ab02">
  <div>
    <h1>Report 3: Analysis &amp; Results</h1>
    <img src="/img/reports/human-face.png" class="imglogo" />
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #9 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 3: (1/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">9</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

<!-- Page #10 -->

<body>
  <div>
    <h1>Report 3: (2/2)</h1>
    <table>...</table>
    <footer>
      <img src="/img/reports/logo.png" class="footer-logo" />
      <div class="page_number">10</div>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can't say that I would recommend this method, but it might work if you *disable the HTML5 parser*. The main use of this parser in dompdf is to correct syntactical errors. Multiple BODY elements are not permitted and so after passing through the HTML5 parser the multiple body elements will be merged into a single element.

Comment: I don't really have another solution right now, however, so carry on.

Comment: Disabling _HTML5 parser_ actually worked for me. Thanks for suggestion and sorry for late response.

Comment: Good to know. Added as an answer for anyone who wanders this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say that I would recommend this method, but it might work if you disable the HTML5 parser. The main use of the HTML5 parser in dompdf is to correct syntactical errors. Multiple BODY elements are not permitted and so after passing through the HTML5 parser the multiple body elements will be merged into a single element.